# What scale contains the pattern - Root, +2, +1, +3, +1, +2, +1, +2?

Tags: scales, terminology, intervals

Intervals (relative to previous note):

```
Root, +2, +1, +3, +1, +2, +1, +2 (Root again)
```

Example:

```
A, B, C, D#, E, F#, G
```

I happened to come across this scale pattern while playing scales on guitar and it somehow feels familiar to me although not sure if it has a name in Western music. Does it?

Answer (score 3):

It's the 4th mode of the harmonic minor scale. Specifically A Dorian ♯4 in your example. For the notes given if you start on E, you'll see the E harmonic minor scale:

```
X: 1
M: C
K: Cmaj
L: 1/8
E^FGA Bc^de||
```

Comment: Also called 'Romanian minor, Ukranian Dorian or minor', I believe.

Comment: It's also known as Mi Sheberakh (lots of variation in the spelling if you're googling it!), one of the three characteristic scales used in klezmer music.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Dom's answer, the clue to working it out as a mode is the tone and a half gap. This only occurs in standard scales in the harmonic minor. So, the gap's between C and D# in your sample, making D# the leading note  - of E harmonic minor. You have a series of notes which make up the basic scale, and have started your cycle on the 4th note, A. Making this the mode called *Dorian #4'*, so called as it is the same as a normal Dorian mode, with the exception of the sharpened 4th note.